# Remove a single item from the list with onClick

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, multidimensional-array, onclick

I have the following object with multiple object arrays. I would like to know how I can remove a single item from the list with onClick.

I know I can try it with the splice, but I have no idea how to do it within this object shape

**State**

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState(initialData || [])
```

I tried like this

**HandleClick**

```
const handleClick = () => {
    const newState = filters
    const index = newState[key].findIndex((a) => a.id === id)

    if (index === -1) return
    newState[key].splice(index, 1)

    setFilters(newState)
  }
```

**Data Object**

```
{
  "services": [
    {
      "id": "1b975589-7111-46a4-b433-d0e3c0d7c08c",
      "name": "Account"
    },
    {
      "id": "91d4637e-a17f-4b31-8675-c041fe06e2ad",
      "name": "Income"
    }
  ],
  "accountTypes": [
    {
      "id": "1f34205b-2e5a-430e-982c-5673cbdb3a68",
      "name": "Investment"
    }
  ],
  "channels": [
    {
      "id": "875f8350-073e-4a20-be20-38482a86892b",
      "name": "Chat"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Render onClick**

```
<div onClick={handleClick}>
   <Icon fileName="smallClose" />
</div>
```

Comment: We do not do homework, don’t say “I don’t know” without given examples you have tried

Comment: @Ernesto, Sorry. I update my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is because you are not declaring the "id" variable anywhere? You can send the element id on the div event if it is on a map loop. I think that could fix your problem.

```
<div onClick={() => handleClick(id)}>
```

And then import it as a parameter on your function:

```
 const handleClick = (id) => {
    const newState = filters
    const index = newState[key].findIndex((a) => a.id === id)

    if (index === -1) return
    newState[key].splice(index, 1)

    setFilters(newState)
  }
```

Also, when you declare the newState value, make sure to use spread operators on the declaration, in your current behavior you are mutating your state and that is not recommended in react:

```
const newState = [...filters];
```

Comment: Cannot find name 'key'

Comment: Yeah, you must declare the "key" variable too. I guess it could have the values "services", "accountTypes" or "channels". You can add it as a parameter among the id too: const handleClick = (id, key) => { ... }. Or you can declare it directly if you want to use one of the specific types: e.g, const key = "services".

Answer (score 1):

when you print the compinent make sure to add them the id of your array

```
<div id={idOfItem} onClick={handleClick}>
   <Icon fileName="smallClose" />
</div>
…….


function handleClick (e) {

e.preventDefault();
const {id} = e.target;

const list = yourItems.filter(item=> item.id!== id);

setItems(list);

}
```

Comment: I get yourItems.filter and replace with filters.filter where filters is my state with the object data. But I receive the message filters.filter is not a function